# Count values based on a condition on another column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a dataset where, for each job department, I count the total amount of people in that department and the total amount of people who left (or not) the company.

```
 Name       Total     Non left    Left
Finance      3000     2500        5000
IT           1500     1000        500
Marketing    1000     750         250
...
```

My initial datase list, row by row, each perosn in the company. My initial data set is:

```
ID    Department  Left
1     Finance     0
2     Finance     1
3     Marketing   0
4     Marketing   0
5     IT          1
...
```

I managed to get the total amount of people per department:

```
df["department"].value_counts()
```

Now I need something that does:

```
df["department"].value_counts(#If element in Left column is 1)
df["department"].value_counts(#If element in Left column is 0)
```

However I am not sure how to start it.

Comment: df["department"][df["Left"]==1].value.counts(), df["department"][df["Left"]==0].value.counts()
Try this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May use `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.Left, df.department ,margins = True)
```